# How to buy a flight ticket for someone else in Condor?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, condor

I am in Europe and my wife is in South America. I'd like to buy her a flight ticket to her to come here. I am not going to fly with her. The most affordable ticket is Condor's but, according to their "Live Chat" person, I can only buy that ticket with a Credit Card even though I could buy using Debit Card from their payment system.

So, I am bit confused if the person who answered me was confused as well.

Does anyone here ever bought a ticket for someone else [in Condor]?

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and try to make the purchase and you'll know if it's declined. Sometimes the online chat reps don't have current information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am regularly buying domestic and international tickets for other people, on various airlines, including Condor; using my *Credit Card* (I'd never use a *Debit Card* online). There never were any issues.
When they ask for passenger name, enter *their* name; when they ask for payment, enter *your* credit card and *your* name.

Note that this might depend on the country the flight starts from; but as Condor is a German airline, your flights are probably starting from Germany, and they do not ask to see the credit card that was used for payment.

My last buy at Condor was in Nov 2016. things could have changed, but I doubt it. My last buys at United and SW were this week.